# Sequelize select distinct rows

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Is there a way to select distinct rows from a table using sequelize.js? 
I looked through the documentation but the "finder methods" do not specify a way to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible automatically but if you don't mind creating the sql on your own, you could do this:

```
sequelize.query('sql goes here', null, { raw: plain }).success(function(data){
    console.log(data)
})
```

Have fun :)

**UPDATE**

1. Sequelize now uses `then` instead of `success` as promise function.
2. `Sequelize.query` has been refactored to only use paramters `sql` and `options`
3. `raw` accepts `true/false` but no `plain` as value.

So, according to the new version, the code should look like this:

```
    sequelize.query('sql goes here', { raw: true }).then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: Ok. I get that :)
Probably in next versions, a bool option {distinct: true} can be added (false being default).

Comment: yep not sure if it will be in the next version but we should add it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30070249/1353897 is the most elegant solution

Answer (score 20):

Assuming you want to apply DISTINCT to the following query:

```
Tuple.findAll({attributes: ['key', 'value']});
```

then this is a (hackish) way to achieve what you want without having to write the whole query yourself:

```
Tuple.findAll({attributes: [[Sequelize.literal('DISTINCT `key`'), 'key'], 'value']});
```

(Tested with Sequelize v2.1.0)

Edit 2015-06-08: Still works with Sequelize v3.1.1

Answer (score 18):

You can do the following:

```
myModel.findAll({
  attributes: [[sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', sequelize.col('col_name')), 'alias_name']],
  where:{}
}).then(data => {}).....
```

taken from [issues](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2996#issuecomment-243636321) and it works.

Comment: NOTE : This solution does not work with `findAndCountAll` method.

Comment: alias_name doesn't work for me when its different then col_name

Comment: how to define `ORDER BY expressions`  for this?

Answer (score 5):

edit your "node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query-generator.js"

at around line 118

change

```
var query = "SELECT <%= attributes %> FROM <%= table %>"
```

into

```
var query = "SELECT " + ((options.distinct)? 'DISTINCT ':'') +"<%= attributes %> FROM <%= table %>",
```

now you can add an option `distinct: true` in your sequelize request

hope it helps -_^

Comment: (... Do not do this.  It will be overwritten the next time you update the package.)

Answer (score 5):

```
Model.findAll({Attributes: ['col_name1', 'col_name2'], group: ['col_name1', 'col_name2']});
```

it's perfectly fine with Sequelize 5.21

Comment: u know what if hace a "distinct" in attributes? `Model.findAll({Attributes: [[Sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', Sequelize.col('id')), 'id'], 'col_name2'], group: ['id', 'col_name2']});`

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat similar to the solution proposed by Pascal Ludwig, but for those landing here looking to get a list of distinct values for a given column, you can do the following:

```
MyModel.aggregate('teh_field', 'DISTINCT', { plain: false }).then(...)
// Resolves to: [ { DISTINCT: value1 }, { DISTINCT: value2 }, ... ]
```

With that, it's easy to transform it into a standard list:

```
MyModel.aggregate('teh_field', 'DISTINCT', { plain: false })
    .map(function (row) { return row.DISTINCT })
    .then(function (tehValueList) {
        // tehValueList = [ value1, value2, ... ]
    })
;
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Sequelize version 1.7, the select query has been moved into lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js.

Around line 1167, change

> mainQueryItems.push("SELECT "+mainAttributes.join ....)

to

> ```
>     mainQueryItems.push('SELECT ');
>     if (options.distinct) {
>         mainQueryItems.push('DISTINCT ');
>     }
>     mainQueryItems.push(mainAttributes.join(', ') + ' FROM ' + options.table);
> ```

By the way, I use Sqlite and Postgres, both of which support "DISTINCT". If you're using a dialect that doesn't support distinct, then obviously this line will cause problems for you, since it will be generated for all the SQL flavors that you're using. I suspect this is why this simple change hasn't made it into the main Sequelize source tree.