# Select rows that are NOT distinct

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

The inverse of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41519695/how-to-get-a-distinct-value-of-a-row-with-sequelize) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156206/sequelize-select-distinct-rows).

I am using Sequelize on Node.js and SQlite. How can I take an existing Sequelize query and make it return only the rows that are not distinct based on columns `name`, `group`, `version` and `rarity`? It needs to avoid selecting the row with the lowest number of all rows that have the same combination of `name`, `group`, `version` and `rarity`.

Maintaining sequelize combability is important because this is a generated query that is used in over a dozen different places, there can be thousands of different combinations of options. All kinds of different where clauses, different includes and the resulting query is used with different sequelize functions, .findAll(), .update() and .count(). So using plain/raw SQL or sequelize.query() means writing a nearly full SQL generator similar to what sequelize does, a non-trivial task.

Example dynamically generated based on user input:

```
let query = {
    where: {
        name: { [sequelize.Op.like]: '%haneul%' },
        owner: "342342234243432"
    },
    include: [{
        model: marketplace,
        required: true,
    }]
}
```

Example data:

| name | group | version | rarity | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| haneul | saturday | IKYK | 1 | 2 |
| haneul | saturday | IKYK | 1 | 3 |
| haneul | saturday | IKYK | 1 | 4 |

Desired result:

| name | group | version | rarity | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| haneul | saturday | IKYK | 1 | 3 |
| haneul | saturday | IKYK | 1 | 4 |

The first row was excluded because it was distinct (lowest number row with that `name`, `group`, `version` and `rarity`).

I tried:

- Using having: `COUNT(*) > 1` and group: `['name', 'group']...`.
- Above grouping but with a where on the having, selecting rows with the lowest number/id.
- A having: with a full sequelize.literal SQL query to check number is bigger than the lowest one.
- A dummy association of the table to itself and adding an include of the table with duplicating: false.
- Making the where clause a [Sequelize.Op.and] between a SQL query (sequelize.literal()) and the existing where clauses.

Comment: Only plain SQL can do the trick

Comment: @Anatoly I understand SQL will be involved, but you mean there is no solution through sequelize other than through sequelize.query() ? Nothing that can retain the existing sequelize where and include?

Comment: You can try to use `sequelize.where` with a subquery

Comment: Or just throw a [raw query](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/raw-queries/) at it.